# ASP.NET BulletedList - Get Selected Item (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bulletedlist

I have a BulletedList in ASP.NET

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="lstItems" OnClick="Item_OnClick" DisplayMode="LinkButton" runat="server" />
```

On the server I handle the list item's link button click event.

**When this occurs I want to apply a CSS class to the selected item on the client-side to show that it is the selected item.**

Since `ListItem` does not support any sort of CSS properties directly, but does support `Selected`, I assume the best way to do this would be to get the selected item from control on the page load and apply the styling then.

Does anyone know how to access this property in JavaScript or any other options to achieve this affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  On the postback, you can add the attributes you need with "attributes.add"

```
Your_Control.Attributes.Add("class", "your_class_name")
```